# ANTLR4 mismatched input '' expecting

Tags: parsing, input, antlr, expect, mismatch

Currently, I've just defined simple rules in ANTLR4:

```
// Recognizer Rules

program  : (class_dcl)+ EOF;
class_dcl: 'class' ID ('extends' ID)? '{' class_body '}';
class_body: (const_dcl|var_dcl|method_dcl)*;
const_dcl: ('static')? 'final' PRIMITIVE_TYPE ID '=' expr ';';
var_dcl: ('static')? id_list ':' type ';';
method_dcl: PRIMITIVE_TYPE ('static')? ID '(' para_list ')' block_stm;
para_list: (para_dcl (';' para_dcl)*)?;
para_dcl: id_list ':' PRIMITIVE_TYPE;
block_stm: '{' '}';
expr: <assoc=right> expr '=' expr | expr1;
expr1: term ('<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' | '==' | '!=') term | term;
term: ('+'|'-') term | term ('*'|'/') term | term ('+'|'-') term | fact;
fact: INTLIT | FLOATLIT | BOOLLIT | ID | '(' expr ')';
type: PRIMITIVE_TYPE ('[' INTLIT ']')?;
id_list: ID (',' ID)*;

// Lexer Rules

KEYWORD: PRIMITIVE_TYPE | BOOLLIT | 'class' | 'extends' | 'if' | 'then' | 'else'
    | 'null' | 'break' | 'continue' | 'while' | 'return' | 'self' | 'final'
    | 'static' | 'new' | 'do';
SEPARATOR: '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '(' | ')' | ';' | ':' | '.' | ',';
OPERATOR: '^' | 'new' | '=' | UNA_OPERATOR | BIN_OPERATOR;
UNA_OPERATOR: '!';
BIN_OPERATOR: '+' | '-' | '*' | '\\' | '/' | '%' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<='
    | '==' | '<>' | '&&' | '||' | ':=';
PRIMITIVE_TYPE: 'integer' | 'float' | 'bool' | 'string' | 'void';
BOOLLIT: 'true' | 'false';
FLOATLIT: [0-9]+ ((('.'[0-9]* (('E'|'e')('+'|'-')?[0-9]+)? ))|(('E'|'e')('+'|'-')? [0-9]+));
INTLIT: [0-9]+;
STRINGLIT: '"' ('\\'[bfrnt\\"]|~[\r\t\n\\"])* '"';
ILLEGAL_ESC: '"' (('\\'[bfrnt\\"]|~[\n\\"]))* ('\\'(~[bfrnt\\"]))
    {if (true) throw new bkool.parser.IllegalEscape(getText());};
UNCLOSED_STRING: '"'('\\'[bfrnt\\"]|~[\r\t\n\\"])*
    {if (true) throw new bkool.parser.UncloseString(getText());};
COMMENT: (BLOCK_COMMENT|LINE_COMMENT) -> skip;
BLOCK_COMMENT: '(''*'(('*')?(~')'))*'*'')';
LINE_COMMENT: '#' (~[\n])* ('\n'|EOF);
ID: [a-zA-z_]+ [a-zA-z_0-9]* ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
ERROR_TOKEN: . {if (true) throw new bkool.parser.ErrorToken(getText());};
```

I opened the parse tree, and tried to test:

```
class abc
{
 final integer x=1;
}
```

It returned errors:

```
BKOOL::program:3:8: mismatched input 'integer' expecting PRIMITIVE_TYPE
BKOOL::program:3:17: mismatched input '=' expecting {':', ','}
```

I still haven't got why. Could you please help me why it didn't recognize rules and tokens as I expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lexer rules are exclusive. The longest wins, and the tiebreaker is the grammar order.

In your case; `integer` is a `KEYWORD` instead of `PRIMITIVE_TYPE`.

What you should do here:

- Make one *distinct* token per keyword instead of an all-catching `KEYWORD` rule.
- Turn `PRIMITIVE_TYPE` into a parser rule
- Same for operators

Right now, your example:

```
class abc
{
 final integer x=1;
}
```

Gets converted to lexemes such as:
`class` `ID` `{` `final` `KEYWORD` `ID` `=` `INTLIT` `;` `}`

This is thanks to the implicit token typing, as you've used definitions such as `'class'` in your parser rules. These get converted to anonymous tokens such as `T_001 : 'class';` which get the highest priority.

If this weren't the case, you'd end up with:
`KEYWORD` `ID` `SEPARATOR` `KEYWORD` `KEYWORD` `ID` `OPERATOR` `INTLIT` `;` `SEPARATOR`

And that's... not quite easy to parse ;-)
That's why I'm telling you to breakdown your tokens properly.

Comment: To avoid new thread, I edit my question for another harder and more confusing question

Comment: Don't do this, this is against SO's standards. Please revert your question to the previous version and post this one as a new question.

Comment: I did open new threadt last night. Fortunately, hours after it, I managed to debug successfully myself. Thank you

Comment: All good then :) I rolled your question back to the previous revision.